# ARFaceTracking and Face Filters on devices without depth camera

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

Apple provides [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_visualizing_faces) for putting 3d content or face filters on people faces. The 3d content tracks face anchor and move according to it. But this function is only supported with devices that have TrueDepth Camera. For example, we can not use ARSCNFaceGeometry without TrueDepth. How Facebook or 3. party SDKs like [Banuba](https://www.banuba.com/) makes this work with devices without depth camera?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, using the [MediaPipe](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_mesh.html) and get face mesh is the only possibility without TrueDepth camera.